# Import Specific Google Sheet Data into WebApp

Tags: google-sheets, html-table, webapp2, import-from-excel

I am trying to develop a WebApp in which user enters his/her id and script will search that ID in the Google sheet and retrieve the respective data row from sheet which contains that ID. Now script is searching the ID in sheet and retrieve the specific row as an array. But I want to import that data in Table in WebApp. But couldn't find any reasonable solution. Following is the script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}
function FetchData(val) {    //'val' is entered by user in WebApp
  
     var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
     var lc=formSS.getLastColumn();
     var lr=formSS.getLastRow();
    
  
     for (var i=2;i<=lr;i++)
       
     {
        var UID = formSS.getRange(i, 1).getValue(); 
       
        if (val==UID)     //Searching Google Sheet ID's and User Entered ID 
          
        {
        
      
        var res=formSS.getRange(i, 1, 1,lc).getValues()[0];
        return res;      //contains the data of specific row which we want to put in WebApp Table
          
        }  
       
     }
}
```

This is HTML Code

```
 <body>
  
   
  <script>
    
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",SearchID);
      
    function SearchID() //Searching ID in Google Sheet
      
    {
      var id=document.getElementById("userid").value;
      google.script.run.FetchData(id);
      document.getElementById("userid").value="";
      
   }
          
  </script>
 
 </body> 
</html>
```

Is there any way that we can put this data in the table of WebApp HTML page. Any Guidance would be much appreciated. This is sheet Link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/119wJ3sBY3coGpEo2CHDnW1hPv_WQbgRaQKUwv7HxyFY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So your askiing how to create a table in html? Try:https://www.google.com/search?q=create+html+table+with+javascript&oq=create+html+table+with+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57.10283j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: There's a guide on how to do this [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication). Specifically, you should be using the [withSuccessHandler()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) method.

Comment: @Cooper I am asking to generate table, but data is coming from Apps Script in an array.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference what the source of data is as long as you understand the format

Comment: Yes, It makes difference when you are communicating apps script with HTML Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, you need to construct a HTML table based on the results received from the server. [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns `Object[][]`, but in your case, the function returns when it finds the first result, so you have only one row.

After receiving that, your useData() function should create a TABLE element using [HTML syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_table.asp), so you need to add tags like `<TABLE>`, `<TR>`, `<TH>` and `<TD>`. These tags can be added to a variable that is used to construct the table, appending tags and their contents as you iterate over the data received:

```
function useData(data) {
  var output = document.getElementById('OutPut');

  // Start building table
  var html = '<table>';

  // Add table header
  html += `<tr>
            <th>Unique ID</th>
            <th>Student name</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Issued on</th>
            <th>certificate link</th>
          </tr>`;

  // Add table row, assuming there's only one row based on what is being done by Apps Script
  html += '<tr>';
  for (var col = 0; col < data[0].length; col++) {
    html += '<td>' + data[0][col] + '</td>';
  }
  html += '</tr>';

  // Stop building table
  html += '</table>';

  // Add table to existing element
  output.innerHTML = html;
}
```